# What's the velocity unit in scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:) states it's `points` (per second, I'm assuming)? However, the values I get for it are in the `(.5, 3.5)` range. The scroll view then travels several hundred points before coming to a halt. The actual initial velocity should be different by orders of magnitude.

Comment: I thought those could be screen or view heights (widths) but that wasn't it either.

Comment: Perhaps it's in points per screen-refresh-interval, which is 1/60th of  a second.  Touch events are reported at the screen refresh interval, so this would make sense.

Comment: I guess it could be, thanks. Problem is, there's still no way to get any meaningful data (e.g. time until it stops) out of the method - because we don't know the deceleration curve.

Comment: Definitely [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) requesting a documentation improvement here. Have you tried per-millisecond?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Perhaps there is another way of looking at it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is points/millisecond. From UIScrollView.h:

```
// called on finger up if the user dragged. velocity is in points/millisecond. targetContentOffset may be changed to adjust where the scroll view comes to rest
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

This is from iOS 7 SDK, which seemed more plausible given the very low values they've been returning in velocity.

Answer (score 1):

From Docs

> called on finger up if the user dragged. velocity is in **points/millisecond**. targetContentOffset may be changed to adjust where the scroll view comes to rest